# Spring Batch with faultTolerant config swallow SQL Exception on commit of a ItemWriter (does a DB rollback but continues Job)

Tags: spring-batch

We make heavy use of Spring Batch (5.0.1) in our new Project (SpringBoot 3.0.5) and MS Sql Server. We like to use the "faultTolerant" feature. eg:

```
return new StepBuilder("abcStep", jobRepository)
     .<String, String>chunk(1, transactionManager)
     .reader(aItemReader)
     .writer(aItemWriter)
     .faultTolerant()
     .backOffPolicy(
         JobCommonConfig.milliSecondsBetweenRetiesPolicy(
            this.milliSecondsBetweenReties))
     .retryLimit(this.retryLimit)
     .retry(Throwable.class)
     .build();
```

Up to now, everything works fine. Now we have found a case where we process data in the ItemWriter that are not ok. Some data is too long for the DB field. We use JPA and do no flush.

```
WARN  o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 2628, SQLState: S0001
ERROR o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : String or binary data would be truncated in table 'abc.dbo.T_.....', column 'FILE_NAME_BASE64'. Truncated value: '....'.
INFO  o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
INFO  o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [aStep] executed in 124ms
```

My expectation would be, on an error, the Step stops with an exception. But this does not happen, it continues the Job. It also rollback my Business transaction.
For use, it looks like everything worked correct, but we just missed some data.

If i add a `flush()` with the entitymanager, i see the exception and Spring Batch behaves as expected and stops the Job.

If i change the Step to this, it also works correct (stop the Job):

```
return new StepBuilder("abcStep", jobRepository)
     .<String, String>chunk(1, transactionManager)
     .reader(aItemReader)
     .writer(aItemWriter)
     .build();
```

I found two entries that could explain the problem:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1189

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3950

What do i wrong? Is the Spring Batch faultTolerant broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We use JPA and do no flush.

> If i add a flush() with the entitymanager, i see the exception and Spring Batch behaves as expected and stops the Job.

This is a known issue when any custom JPA item writer does **not** flush. This is probably a documentation issue, but you need to `flush` items in your custom writer. This is **not** a workaround. This is mentioned in the issue you linked and also [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1826#issuecomment-566286912).

The `JpaItemWriter` provided by Spring Batch does flush items in the `write` method, and behaves as expected when an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1) Better Docu would help. 2) We use Spring Batch to be sure not to lose any data. But exactly this happened. I my strong Opinion, Spring Batch should never ever loose data. I would expect an Exception to be thrown, not a ERROR msg.

Comment: It will not loose data if you use the built-in `JpaItemWriter` (since it flushes items correctly). Now if you write a custom writer and you flush as well, Spring Batch won't loose data neither. Spring Batch can do nothing if you provide a buggy item writer. Do you agree? But again, we can improve the docs WTR. Please open an issue on GitHub and we will improve things.